# How to apply every of many predicate functions (`and` them)

Tags: clojure

I have many predicate functions in a vector `fs`, and would like to `and` them all together. This <s>works</s> for the first two functions:

```
((and (first fs) (second fs)) value)
```

However I would like to write code that applies `and` to all the functions, no matter how many there are. `(apply and fs)` does not compile because `and` is a macro.

For an example of predicate functions <s>working</s> with `and`, try this:

```
((and number? integer?) 1)
```

**Edit** In case you don't read the comments, both `and` constructions above are BAD EXAMPLES. For same constructions to actually work use `every-pred` rather than `and`.

Comment: Have you tried putting them in a `do` block?

Comment: No - would not be sure how to do that or why would want to - no side effects

Comment: I've edited my answer.  I am pretty sure every-pred does exactly what you want.

Comment: Fixed the code snippet, I apologize.

Comment: Your last example with `and` doesn't actually work. `and` returns the last truthy value and functions are truthy, so only the last function is called. Try `((and string? integer?) 1)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are working with predicates, [every-pred](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/every-pred) may be of interest.

After reading your edit - thanks, I didn't know and you could do that with `and`.  Additionally I've edited my answer, and I think you definitely want to apply every-pred

```
((apply every-pred [number? integer?]) 1)
=> true
((apply every-pred [number? integer?]) "asdf")
=> false
```

Comment: I fixed it, sorry about that.

Comment: To be explicit, the required function is `(partial apply every-pred)`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `every-pred` is a good answer to this question (I hadn't noticed it before!).  [A related function that may be handy](http://A%20related%20function%20that%20may%20be%20handy) is `juxt`.  It applies a number of functions to a single argument:

```
((juxt a b c) x) => [(a x) (b x) (c x)]
```

Note that, unlike `every-pred`, the `juxt` function does not short-circuit and always evaluates each function in the list.  An example:

```
(ns tst.clj.core
  (:use clj.core clojure.test tupelo.test)
  (:require [tupelo.core :as t] ))

(defn f2 [x] (zero? (mod x 2)))
(defn f3 [x] (zero? (mod x 3)))
(defn f5 [x] (zero? (mod x 5)))

(def f235 (apply juxt [f2 f3 f5] ))
```

This gives us results:

```
(f235 2) => [true false false]
(f235 3) => [false true false]
(f235 5) => [false false true]
(f235 6) => [true true false]
(f235 10) => [true false true]
(f235 15) => [false true true]
(f235 30) => [true true true]

(every? truthy? (f235 15)) => false
(every? truthy? (f235 30)) => true
```

where the `truthy?` function is similar to `boolean`:

```
(defn truthy?
  "Returns true if arg is logical true (neither nil nor false); otherwise returns false."
  [arg]
  (if arg true false))
```

---

P.S.  Please note that your original example does not say `(and (f1 x) (f2 x))` but instead says `(and f1 f2) => f1`.   So when you type

```
(def fs [f1 f2 f3 f4])
((and (first fs) (second fs)) value)

=> ((and f1 f2) value)
=> (f1 value)
```

which does not give the result you were seeking.